How to escape single quote in flutter's .arb files?
I have the following in my intl_en.arb file:
"title_chef_selection": "Chef's Selection",
"@title_chef_selection": {},

And I get this error: Error: Unbalanced escape quotes. To escape a single quote ', prefix it with another single quote.(mismatched_brackets)
I followed it's advice changing it to this:
"title_chef_selection": "Chef''s Selection",
"@title_chef_selection": {},

This shows two single quotes in Text(S.of(context).title_chef_selection)
I just tried this one:
"title_chef_selection": "Chef\'s Selection",
"@title_chef_selection": {},

I get this error: Invalid escape character in string.json(261), but it works and the text shows properly. Is there a different way of doing it or a way to get rid of the error?

You can turn off escaping quotes by updating/including l10n.yaml file with the following line:
use-escaping: false


This just solved my problem, thanks

I solved disabling the Arb extension in Visual Studio Code.

I don't think disabling the extension is the solution to this problem.

Single quotes need not be escaped in JSON. Only double quotes needs to be escaped. This might be due to the issue in some other line. Will you be able to share the whole code

{   "@@locale": "en",   "title_chef_selection": "Chef's Selection",   "@title_chef_selection": {} } 
